# MariaDB 10.4. No traffic yet high CPU usage

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a problem with which i fail to win. Have new server set up with Debian 10 (64) and MariaDB 10.4. There's no traffic on this server yet. So no slow queries or queries in total however, MariaDB takes 300% CPU already. No matter what I do and how i tinker configuration. IT's always this way.
What is enabled: data at rest encryption. There was replication from it (MASTER to SLAVE) but i switched it off suspecting it could be it, but not...
Iotop shows no data writes that could cause this CPU usage, so what is going on, anyone had such problem?

```
    PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
24419 mysql      20   0 19.4G 2008M 23268 S 299.  5.5 22:51.15 /usr/sbin/mysqld
24445 mysql      20   0 19.4G 2008M 23268 S 79.3  5.5  5:40.03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
24448 mysql      20   0 19.4G 2008M 23268 R 76.1  5.5  5:38.87 /usr/sbin/mysqld
24446 mysql      20   0 19.4G 2008M 23268 R 72.4  5.5  5:41.99 /usr/sbin/mysqld
24447 mysql      20   0 19.4G 2008M 23268 R 70.9  5.5  5:39.02 /usr/sbin/mysqld


MariaDB [(none)]> show full processlist;
+-----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
| Id  | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                    | Info                  | Progress |
+-----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
|   1 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|   2 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|   3 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|   4 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|   5 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL                  |    0.000 |
| 134 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | Init                     | show full processlist |    0.000 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)

Total DISK READ:         0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:         0.00 B/s
Current DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Current DISK WRITE:      59.00 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
  430 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [jbd2/dm-0-8]
14633 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/5:0-mm_percpu_wq]
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_gp]
    4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_par_gp]
    6 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H-events_highpri]
    8 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:1H-events_highpri]
    9 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [mm_percpu_wq]
   10 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
   11 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
   12 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_bh]
   13 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
   15 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/0]

root@as1:/home/lukasz# uptime
 09:24:36 up 8 days, 1 min,  4 users,  load average: 2.90, 2.86, 2.94
```

EDIT: version: 10.4.27-MariaDB-1:10.4.27+maria~deb10-log
EDIT: show engine innodb status:

```
    =====================================
2022-11-22 09:53:59 0x7fe4a44fd700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 55 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 149 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 1921 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 2070
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 45741
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 22662
RW-shared spins 1314, rounds 24199, OS waits 636
RW-excl spins 26, rounds 586, OS waits 13
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 18.42 RW-shared, 22.54 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1029611
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1029611 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 7
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 422094963908992, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422094963904776, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422094963900560, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
52839 OS file reads, 4450 OS file writes, 2433 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.07 writes/s, 0.07 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 81, seg size 83, 88 merges
merged operations:
 insert 114, delete mark 6, delete 3
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 84 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 187 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 133 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 105 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 83 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 148 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 42 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 147 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 118676575056
Log flushed up to   118676575056
Pages flushed up to 118676575056
Last checkpoint at  118676575047
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
958 log i/o's done, 0.07 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 8606711808
Dictionary memory allocated 966240
Buffer pool size   513728
Free buffers       458354
Database pages     49418
Old database pages 18397
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 6, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49264, created 154, written 2896
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 49418, unzip_LRU len: 10504
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       57916
Database pages     5564
Old database pages 2073
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 5560, created 4, written 323
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 5564, unzip_LRU len: 1282
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       58029
Database pages     5539
Old database pages 2064
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 5539, created 0, written 134
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 5539, unzip_LRU len: 1104
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       57604
Database pages     5919
Old database pages 2204
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 5918, created 1, written 108
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 5919, unzip_LRU len: 1206
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       56793
Database pages     6636
Old database pages 2469
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 6614, created 22, written 777
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6636, unzip_LRU len: 1441
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       56203
Database pages     7075
Old database pages 2631
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 7075, created 0, written 704
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 7075, unzip_LRU len: 1725
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       56942
Database pages     6403
Old database pages 2383
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 6403, created 0, written 58
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6403, unzip_LRU len: 1549
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       57495
Database pages     6117
Old database pages 2278
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 6054, created 63, written 561
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6117, unzip_LRU len: 1037
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   64216
Free buffers       57372
Database pages     6165
Old database pages 2295
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 6101, created 64, written 231
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6165, unzip_LRU len: 1160
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=14405, Main thread ID=140610963961600, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 107, updated 488, deleted 12, read 22433827
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 1
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Which exact 10.4 version? What does `show engine innodb status` show? (edit this into the question).

Comment: @danblack updated. Thanks

Comment: Does the excessive CPU usage go away if you disable Data At Rest Encryption? FYI: Similar issue discussed [here](https://kb-mirror.mariadb.com/kb/en/high-cpu-usage-when-tde-is-enabled/) (Q&As in MariaDB KB).

Comment: @dbdemon yes, updated my question couple minutes ago. reduced threads=1 and problem went away

Comment: Very good! You should post it as an answer to your own question. That could earn you some points, and it's more helpful for other users that way.

Answer (score 3):

Ok i found out it was caused by innodb-encrypt-tables=FORCE and innodb-encrypt-threads=4, after reducing down to =1 problem (load) disappeared.

Comment: Does setting it to 1 slow down things significantly?

Comment: @RickJames time will show, i have no traffic on this server yet.... (never had)